# Get only the response code not the full source of a url

Tags: java, http, url

I have an URL and i want only to check the response code of the page and not the complete page source as fetching the the complete page source is quite slow. what is right way to go ?

does getResponseCode() in HttpUrlConnection feches the complete page source or only the header ?

Comment: int respCode = ((HttpURLConnection)conn).getResponseCode(); will return response code

Comment: I would say, no, it doesn't download the content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Straight from the docs, [HttpUrlConnection#getResponseCode()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html#getResponseCode%28%29)

> Gets the status code from an HTTP response message. For example, in the case of the following status lines:
>    HTTP/1.0 200 OK
>    HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized
>
> It will return 200 and 401 respectively. Returns -1 if no code can be discerned from the response (i.e., the response is not valid HTTP).

Answer (score 0):

Depends what you're motivation is in making the request. If the request is normally just a GET request for a resource and doesn't have any side effects.

You can perform a HTTP HEAD request instead, which if implemented correctly should get you the same status codes but not the body. (i.e. setRequestMethod(HEAD))

Answer (score 0):

```
Here method may be PostMethod or GetMethod
```

you can get status code from an HTTP response message by getStatusCode()

example:-
int statuscode=method.getStatusCode();